# why adding a size or button code in tkinter gives this error?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

i was having some problem in tkinter GUI in python. i write the code to open a blank window :

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.mainloop()
```

in this moment , there is no error and opens a blank window. but when i want to add label or button or window size , like this code :

```
from tkinter import *
window =  Tk()
window.mainloop()

window.minsize(400,300)
window.maxsize(640,450)

window.geometry('350x200')
```

now in this code , i wrote a size change code . but it gives an error now and the size code doesnt work. it gives the following error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Green\Desktop\coding\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    window.minsize(400,300)
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2196, in wm_minsize
    return self._getints(self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "wm" command: application has been destroyed
```

can you help me in this code ? thanks.

Comment: The added code should be put before `window.mainloop()`.

Comment: window.mainloop() should be last line in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widgets need to go in between `window = Tk()` and `window.mainloop`. So, try:

```
    from tkinter import *
    window =  Tk()

    window.minsize(400,300)
    window.maxsize(640,450)

    window.geometry('350x200')

    # Code to add widgets will go here...
    # For example:
    button = Button(window, text="example button")
    button.pack()

    window.mainloop()
```